# How can I get city name from geolocation data in node express mongoose mongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this document in my collection inside a db in MongoDB

```
{
 name: "steve",
 id: 11,
 address: "24 rue Victor Hugo"
 geolocation:
 {latitude:"16.66667",longitude:"101.18333"}
}
```

I want to get the city name from the geolocation data, I am working in Vs with node, express and mongoose. I tried to find a way to do without manipulating my db, because I already have my collection set before starting.

Comment: To get that information you'd be looking possibly using Googles Geocoding API you will have to have a look at its documentation, I was going to add a link but its too long to post

Comment: while you may use google or openstreetmap or whatsoever service which offers **reverse geocoding** you may check your lng/lat because I dont think your point lies in france (address victor hugo looking a lot like a french address) :). Given your question is not verifiable since you don't specify the expected city, I will just cite [an fr geoservice](https://geo.api.gouv.fr/adresse) because it is not *that* easily findable on the web

Answer (score 2):

You can make requests with your geolocation parameters for address information.
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: is this a library I have to install or I can just use a link?where did you get this link?thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview   You can get information from here. When you create account in google it gives you credit for using its services. This credit is enough for development.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called reverse geocoding. It is available through the Google Maps Geocoding API. You have to sign up for a Google Developers account. Afterwards, you create a project from the Google Developers console. You can then request an API key. You can then use this API key in your request to the Google Maps API as follows:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=16.66667,101.18333&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Take a look at Google's Goecoding API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_397052992307-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20%7E%20Places%20%7C%20BMM%20%7C%20Google%20Maps%20Geocoding%20API-KWID_43700049595992106-kwd-313687192697-userloc_1003297&utm_term=KW_%2Bgoogle%20%2Bmaps%20%2Bgeocoding-ST_%2Bgoogle%20%2Bmaps%20%2Bgeocoding&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIvNWo19i27gIVEAB7Ch3FegPpEAAYASAAEgKMGvD_BwE). You can also test that URL in a browser to see the returned JSON-result, or using [curl](https://curl.se/) from the command-line.